Why is reverse stock split exist on stock market?
What's the purpose of reverse split? It combines several stocks into one, and after that, what if the management decided to issue new shares?

I think part of the confusion here is that stock splits generally happen because the company's value has grown enough that share prices are inconvenient, and reverse splits happen because the company's value has shrunk enough to make share prices inconvenient. But the split or reverse split is just recognizing and compensating for something that  has already happened. People getting excited or depressed about either are focusing on the wrong thing. (And may be late to the party.)

It combines several shares into one, and that's it. The purpose is to reduce the number of outstanding shares, while increasing the value of each individual share. This can be useful if, for example, the value of each individual share pre-split falls below the threshold required by the stock exchange where the shares are listed.
Reverse splits (or regular splits) are not changing the underlying value and do not change any ownership stakes, they do not rip anyone off. You're confusing with dilution of shares, which does in fact happen when new shares are issued, but has nothing to do with splits. In the case of new shares, the existing investors retain their value, but there's an additional value added to the company through the investment of the new shareholders, and as such each existing shareholder is diluted (they keep the same value, but lesser portion of the total).

falls below the threshold required by the stock exchange where the shares are listed this is exactly what I meant ripping ppl off, if it falls below it should be just delisted. Reverse split artificially inflates the price so that it will fall again.

@fluter why is delisting better for investors than consolidating? Price per share is a meaningless number and limits on it are for convenience or technical

I see. thanks for the answer!

Reverse split does not "inflate the price". It changes the size of the unit, not the value. Whether you own ten $50 bills or fifty $10 bills doesn't matter in terms of value, but it is a lot more convenient to work with the former. You could also have one $500 bill, which has its own inconveniences. A split or reverse split just divides your N% ownership of the company into a different number of shares for convenience of trading. Value is unchanged. Dividends paid per percent ownership is unchanged.  It's strictly a bookkeeping process.

Let's start from the other end. When a stock splits, each shareholder gets more shares but each share is now worth less. The reason for doing it is to make it easier for small investors to buy shares. If you're stock is trading at, say, $5,000 per share, many investors won't be willing or able to come up with the money to buy even 1 share. If you have a 10 to 1 split and now it's $500 per share, well that's more manageable.
A company may do a reverse split when their share price is so low that it is inconvenient. Like if your share price is 10 cents per share, that's just a pain to deal with. A 1 cent change in price is 10%, which is a lot, so people start having to deal with fractions of a penny per share. And there's the psychological impact that a low share price makes people think your company is weak or doing poorly.

The unpleasant process I was refering to is that price goes too low, board decided to reverse split, so holders has less shares now(yes, same value), but then mgmt decided to issue new shares, so the holders has much less voting power than before the reverse split. In addition that  the price can keep doing down after the reverse split.

@fluter: The reverse split has zero effect in the scenario you've described. The new shares are equivalent to two of the old shares, but folks had to pay twice as much to get them; if the RS hadn't been done they'd have bought twice as many shares and the same effect on voting would occur. Percentage of ownership is percentage of ownership, however many shares it's nominally divided into.

And yes, price can continue to decline. But that too is unaffected by the split. Losing or gaining 1% of value, again, doesn't care how many shares it's spread across. The reverse split is not really intended to alter the stock's trajectory.

@fluter If the company issues new stock, sure, that dilutes the voting power of those with existing shares. But as Keshlam says, this has nothing to do with the reverse split. If they hadn't done the split and issued new shares, that would also dilute the votes of existing shareholders. And presumably if they issue new shares, they are concerned with the dollar value of those shares, not the nominal number. That is, if they decide to do a new issue, they're ...

... not going to say, "We've decided to issue another 100,000 shares. Now let's look up how much that would be worth." They're going to say, "We've decided to issue another $100,000 worth of stock. Now let's see how many shares that is."
